# Install libicui18n locally on CentOS

Tags: centos, rstudio

I tried installing `Seurat` package in `Rstudio`, in a `markdown` file and apparently I need to install `libicui18n` locally on `CentOS` for it to work:

https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4148/seurat-installation-fails

I do not have `root` permissions. So, is there a way to do this?

Comment: ? Which CentOS version ?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

Answer (score 0):

> libicui18n

```
libicudata.so.50 -> libicudata.so.50.1.2
libicudata.so.50.1.2
libicui18n.so.50 -> libicui18n.so.50.1.2
libicui18n.so.50.1.2
libicuio.so.50 -> libicuio.so.50.1.2
libicuio.so.50.1.2
libicule.so.50 -> libicule.so.50.1.2
libicule.so.50.1.2
libiculx.so.50 -> libiculx.so.50.1.2
libiculx.so.50.1.2
libicutest.so.50 -> libicutest.so.50.1.2
libicutest.so.50.1.2
libicutu.so.50 -> libicutu.so.50.1.2
libicutu.so.50.1.2
libicuuc.so.50 -> libicuuc.so.50.1.2
libicuuc.so.50.1.2
```

The files depend on each other, else no special dependencies. Packed as lib64/libicu*.so... → `libicu-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64.tar.gz`, which you can unpack in any location in $HOME.

Link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mt62sCzGvSVkj5-osQhk466ImZ5XjPQt?usp=sharing ( `libicu-devel-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64.tar.gz` is present too in the link.)